# angular redirect from list to details - use shared service or pass id and call webservice

Tags: java, angularjs

I have list view with let's say four columns: id, name, description and value. Then I want to redirect to item details view. I'm using `angular-ui ui-router`. What is better practice:

1. Use shared service where I can store selected object on list view (ex. call `setSelectedItem`) and on details page I should call `getSelectedItem`.
2. Pass in URL selected item id (ex. `my_app/#/details/SELECTED_ITEM_ID`) and on details view call REST service for item details ex. `POST my_app/services/getItemDetails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use both of them...
it is a common way to share object between controllers via services but it should be managed carefully.

passing id of and object and get data from server is a trusted way, but if you have already full object in your list view and you are sure that there will be not change on the object then you maybe do not want to make an extra call to server...

as I mentioned in the second argument if you just want to share object without making a call you use **resolve** attribute of angular-ui router as well... you can find detailed information in [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)...

but do you have a guarantee that object will not change at this time ?

Comment: Yes, I have guarantee that object will not change at this time. I'm struggling myself with the question should my app be more secure and make and extra call to server or should I use shared service to store the whole object. But you have written that both way are correct.

Comment: user can refresh page at details page and your sharedService's data will be cleared which cause to loose all data... there can be many scenario like this...

Comment: So should I use this shared service like a cache on Angular side? Store not only one element but for ex. 20 elements? I need to find good article about using shared services I guess.

Comment: I am only using this when I need to pass a data to another controller in same page like directive's controller. it is more like a template variable...

Comment: Thank you for whole explanation. Now I know that I need to be more carefully when I want to use shared service. I've decided to make and extra call to server to be more "secure".